# match occurrences of a string to a substring

Tags: python, pandas

I have:

| phrase | len |
| --- | --- |
| i love | 2 |
| he plays | 2 |
| i love people | 3 |
| love | 1 |

I have a dataframe, for each cell I want to find its occurrence in other cells and display it in a separate column

I have tried this

```
for i in range(len(df['phrase'])):
     for j in range(len(df['phrase'])):
         if (df['phrase'].iloc[i] in df['phrase'].iloc[j]) and (df['phrase'].iloc[i] != df['phrase'].iloc[j]):
             df['match'].iloc[i]=df['phrase'].iloc[j]
```

I expected this:

| phrase | match |
| --- | --- |
| i love | i love people |
| i love people | non |
| love | i love |
| love | i love people |
| he plays | non |

Comment: What are you getting that is incorrect when running this? Is this portion of your IF `(df['phrase'].iloc[i] != df['phrase'].iloc[j])` intended to prevent you pulling the same cell in that you're searching for? You could just use ` if (df['phrase'].iloc[i] in df['phrase'].iloc[j]) and (i != j):` instead

Comment: it returns same values ​​in 'match' column

Comment: Does a phrase like "I love" should match "People love I"?

Comment: no, word order matters

Comment: @МихаилБеляков Can you update your OP with an example of what you are receiving so that we may compare it against what you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
import pandas as pd

# Your dataset
data = [['i love', 2], ['he plays', 2], ['i love people', 3], ['love', 1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['phrase', 'len'])

# Find phrases and matchs
init_phrases=list(df['phrase'])
phrases=[]
matchs=[]
for i in range(len(init_phrases)) :
    init_phrase=init_phrases[i]
    match_found=False
    for j in range(len(init_phrases)) :
        if i!=j :
            compare_phrase=init_phrases[j]
            if init_phrase in compare_phrase :
                phrases.append(init_phrase)
                matchs.append(compare_phrase)
                match_found=True
    if match_found==False :
        phrases.append(init_phrase)
        matchs.append("non")

# Output dataset    
df_output=pd.DataFrame({"phrase":phrases,"match":matchs})
df_output
```

Comment: thnx bro, it works better then my

Comment: how to change the code so that it was possible to check the occurrences of each element (word) of a string in a string, the order is not important